# Accidentally downloaded a Trojan.Dropper which Malwarebytes picked up, how to ensure system is clean?

Tags: malware, windows, attacks, trojan

So I was trying to download an arcade game, everything seemed legit and I guess I was too excited to play it I started running it - only after clicking it I decided to run a scan on both Avira and Malwarebytes. As it was running Malwarebytes picked up a Trojan.Dropper, the game itself works but I deleted it promptly after quarantining the malicious file.

Now reading about droppers says they tend to alter your registry keys and create hidden files. In fact, Avira sent a prompt saying something just tried to edit my registry. I have no idea how to look for those to ensure my system is clean. How should I go about that? I've done a full system scan on both the software.

I've used a registry scanner and scanned for changes in the registry within 1 min before/after the item was quarantined which came up to about 101 entries, would it be best to put that into a pastebin to see if anything could have been malicious?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't trust your system, simply reformat.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you have two options here:

- Hope that those scans picked up everything and continue using the computer.
- Do what @Will suggested and completely reinstall Windows from a fresh installation.

Personally, I would do a reinstall, as you don't know if Malwarebytes and Avira picked up every part of the dropper Trojan. If you don't want to do a complete reinstall, but want to attempt to remove the traces of the Trojan, you could try using Windows' System Restore feature, if there is a restore point available before you downloaded the game.

Answer (score 0):

A third option (which imho is a bit better than just using the regular scan but obviously not as safe as a complete reinstall) would be to use a (or even better multiple) rescue disc that many of the antivirus companies offer (like  [this](https://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/655) <- haven't tried that particular one, just the first one google threw at me).

These allow to scan the system when it is not running which makes it a bit harder for the malware to hide.
If you happen to be from germany you could also give  [desinfec't](https://www.heise.de/download/product/desinfect-71642) a shot. It's not free but it's a rescue disc that uses multiple engines to scan you pc (amongst other things) and quite a handy tool.

Comment: Ooh, that's a good idea. I keep forgetting that these utilities exist. You can also use Linux Live CDs and then use an antivirus solution from there, such as `clamav`. It's free, and you can do a lot of other stuff, such as edit the Windows registry hive and manage disk partitions.